# Matplotlib plot is not displaying all xticks and yticks

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am creating subplots in matplotlib but not all xticks and yticks are being displayed. I have tried everything from setting xlim and ylim, chainging figure size etc. The thing is this is a handson on hackerrnak and they are evaluating my output against their expected output. The 0.0 in xaxis and 1.0 on yaxis are simply not matching up. What am I doing wrong here.

Here is the code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def test_generate_figure2():
    np.random.seed(1000)
    x = np.random.rand(10)
    y = np.random.rand(10)
    z = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
    axes1 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 1, title="Scatter plot with Upper Triangle Markers")
    axes1.set_xticks([0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2])
    axes1.set_yticks([-0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0])
    axes1.set_ylim(-0.2,1.0) #Doing this still doesnot get the expected output
    axes1.set_xlim(0.0,1.2)
    print(axes1.get_yticks())
    axes1.scatter(x, y, marker="^", s=80, c=z)
    
    axes2 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 2, title="Scatter plot with Plus Markers")
    axes2.set_xticks([0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2])
    axes2.set_yticks([-0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0])
    axes2.scatter(x, y, marker="+", s=80, c=z)
    
    axes3 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 3, title="Scatter plot with Circle Markers")
    axes3.set_xticks([0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2])
    axes3.set_yticks([-0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0])
    axes3.scatter(x, y, marker="o", s=80, c=z)
    
    axes4 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 4, title="Scatter plot with Diamond Markers")
    axes4.set_xticks([0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2])
    axes4.set_yticks([-0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0])
    axes4.scatter(x, y, marker="d", s=80,c=z)
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    
test_generate_figure2()
```

My Output,
[image: My Output]
Expected Output,
[image: Expected Outpput]

Comment: You are setting your ticks before the scatter call; set them after.  You may want to also consider using subplots with the sharex=True and shared=True options.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thanks your solution works. I was setting ticks without plotting anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as caused by a typo / not reproducible, since the author stated the comment by @JodyKlymak resolved the issue. The comment was made to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69263661/7758804) below.

Answer (score 0):

Your `set_xlim` & `set_ylim` approach works. You just need to set it for every subplot:

https://akuiper.com/console/5vaLIq0ZC_KO

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def test_generate_figure2():
    np.random.seed(1000)
    x = np.random.rand(10)
    y = np.random.rand(10)
    z = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
    axes1 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 1, title="Scatter plot with Upper Triangle Markers")
    axes1.set_xticks([0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2])
    axes1.set_yticks([-0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0])
    axes1.set_ylim(-0.2,1.0) #Doing this still doesnot get the expected output
    axes1.set_xlim(0.0,1.2)
    print(axes1.get_yticks())
    axes1.scatter(x, y, marker="^", s=80, c=z)

    axes2 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 2, title="Scatter plot with Plus Markers")
    axes2.set_xticks([0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2])
    axes2.set_yticks([-0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0])
    axes2.set_ylim(-0.2,1.0) #Doing this still doesnot get the expected output
    axes2.set_xlim(0.0,1.2)

    axes2.scatter(x, y, marker="+", s=80, c=z)

    axes3 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 3, title="Scatter plot with Circle Markers")
    axes3.set_xticks([0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2])
    axes3.set_yticks([-0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0])
    axes3.set_ylim(-0.2,1.0) #Doing this still doesnot get the expected output
    axes3.set_xlim(0.0,1.2)

    axes3.scatter(x, y, marker="o", s=80, c=z)

    axes4 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 4, title="Scatter plot with Diamond Markers")
    axes4.set_xticks([0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2])
    axes4.set_yticks([-0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0])
    axes4.set_ylim(-0.2,1.0) #Doing this still doesnot get the expected output
    axes4.set_xlim(0.0,1.2)

    axes4.scatter(x, y, marker="d", s=80,c=z)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

test_generate_figure2()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I had tried that but couldnot get that little gap before 0.0, @JodyKlymak solution works though. Thanks for the solution anyways.